# Twitter API: How to get sender IP Address?

Tags: twitter

I would like to get the IP Address / hostname / device (ios, android, web) for a specific tweet  via Twitter API or anything similar.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 2):

There's absolutely no way to get IP address or hostname.  That would be a massive privacy violation.

You can make a *very* rough guess at device by looking at the `source` parameter of a Tweet.

If it says `"source":"Twitter for iPhone"` you'll know it is coming from an iPhone.  Not every source says which device it is running on.

Comment: Yes "source" is a good guess. Of course Im thinking on query my own tweets so maybe it doesnt violate any privacy.